# Build a bibliography after my PhD corpus

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I built my PhD thesis by writing each chapter in different .tex documents.
I have one `.bib` document with all the references for my PhD.
I am using natbib in my preamble but I am open to use different `bib` tricks.
I have a `main.tex` document for declaring packages for my PhD, building my cover page and include my chapter such as:

```
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\include{Chap1.tex}

X references are cited.

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\include{Chap2.tex}

Y references are cited.

\bibliography{references}
```

I have references in each chapter and I would like all the references to appear in my bibliography part. The issue I have is that I only have the X references cited in the first chapter which are referenced in the bibliography part of my PhD. the other Y references cited in my Chapter 2 are not present and the appear as [?] in my text.

Comment: The setup seems to be ok, so there may be a problem in the execution, or your real document contains some additional code that interferes with the setup. It is difficult to tell without more information. Some common issues: did you run `bibtex` again after adding the second chapter? Is the `.bib` file valid (check for example by including chapter 2 first, does this cause the references from chapter 2 to appear)? Do you get any errors or warnings from either BibTeX or LaTeX? Possibly also deleting auxiliary files will solve the issue.

Comment: A good first step for troubleshooting is to actually implement the example code as you have given, with two dummy `Chap1.tex` and `Chap2.tex` files with each containing only a citation and nothing else, then try to run the example and see if it has the same problem. If yes then post the full runnable code here. If not then gradually keep adding contents from your real document until the problem appears.

Comment: I recompiled the doc after adding the second chapter and no evolution, bibliography is still full from Chapter 1 but without the ones from Chapter 2
I tried to include the second chapter first but this doesn't work ...
I don't have particular errors concerning the bibliography.

I am using a \usepackage[français]{babel} but doesn't seem to cause problem

Comment: I'm not sure how you compile the document (via some editor like TeXstudio, or via the command prompt, or on Overleaf, or something else?) but you need to make sure you run LaTeX, after that run BibTeX, after that run LaTeX again. Most editors do this automatically when you press the right button but maybe this is causing the issue (you are pressing the wrong button, or you compile on the command prompt and forgot BibTeX, or there actually is an error but your editor is hiding it from you).

Comment: I am using Overleaf to compile my document

Comment: I am using pdfLaTex in Overleaf*